# Quick way to indent copy-paste buffer?

Tags: linux, copy-paste

A lot of times I want to copy some error message and paste it into some web form indented by 2 or 4 spaces. Is there a quick way to modify the contents of my copy-paste buffer to add an N-space indent?

Currently I open vim, paste into vim, indent, copy back out of vim, paste into the destination, then close vim.

Comment: I was about to suggest what you're already doing. Creating a script is probably the next step. Just use sed or perl to `s/^/  /g` and a script to paste from clipboard, call sed, copy to clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this one-liner using `xsel` to indent the clipboard by 2 spaces:

```
$ xsel -b | sed -e's/^/  /' | xsel -b --input
```

You can replace the `"  "` in the sed expression with whatever number of spaces/tabs or other prefix you want.